# TYPE_VIEW_CLICKED not issued in Android Accessibility Service

Tags: android, accessibility

I have created my own accessibility service which listens to all events. The primary purpose of my service is to just capture what the user has clicked on so for the most part, I use TYPE_VIEW_CLICKED which works fine in most cases and I'm able to see what the user clicked on. However, there are cases in some apps on some buttons, TYPE_VIEW_CLICKED is not emitted and only TYPE_WINDOW_CONTENT_CHANGED and TYPE_WINDOW_STAGE_CHANGED are emitted. The problem with these are, when I search their accessibilityNodeInfo's, they don't have the text on what the user clicked. Also even if they did, these types of events doesn't necessarily guarantee that the user clicked on that text (button), but rather it changed to that text.

I'm guessing these apps probably implemented their own onTouch and did not follow practice to implement the accessibility methods.

I'm utterly stuck here and I have no idea how to capture it.

Here is my config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<accessibility-service xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:accessibilityEventTypes="typeAllMask"
    android:canRequestEnhancedWebAccessibility="true"
    android:accessibilityFlags="flagDefault"
    android:accessibilityFeedbackType="feedbackAllMask"
    android:notificationTimeout="100"
    android:canRetrieveWindowContent="true"
    android:canRequestFilterKeyEvents="true"
    android:canRequestTouchExplorationMode="true"
    />
```